# Can I use hook_block_info() in a theme?

Tags: blocks, theming

In Drupal 7, can I use [hook_block_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7) in a theme?

I would like my theme to create a block (which would contain dynamic content). This will allow the user to move it around where he wants to, or simply hide it.

Is this the way to go?

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block_info() 
 */
function mytemplate_block_info()
{
  $blocks['mytemplate-block'] = array(
    'info' => t('TemplateBlock'),
    'weight' => -100,
    'status' => 1,
    'region' => 'content',
    'visibility' => BLOCK_VISIBILITY_LISTED,
    'pages' => '<front>',
  );

  return $blocks;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_block_view() 
 */
function mytemplate_block_view($delta = '')
{
  $block = array();

  switch ($delta) {
    case 'mytemplate-block':
      $block['content'] = 'some custom html';
    break;

  }

  return $block;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't, no, it has to be in a module.

The array of blocks is built up in [`_block_render_blocks()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.module/function/_block_render_blocks/7) using the [`module_invoke()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_invoke/7) function which, as its name suggests, only invoke hooks for modules and not themes.

If you haven't written a custom module before don't be afraid to get stuck in its pretty easy. I'd highly recommend the [Module Developer's Guide](http://drupal.org/developing/modules) which will tell you everything you need to know.

Comment: Thanks I'll food another way then!I am familiar with modules but not themes and was wondering if I could also build blocks from themes. I appreciate your help!